# Java compiler cannot find hadoop.hbase.mapreduce packages

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to run a MapReduce app which uses a HBase table. The code is provided by my university professor and we are supposed to run it. Here is the code:

```
package hbase;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter;

public class HBaseMapReduce {

    public static class hbaseMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {

        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey, Result columns, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                String inKey = new String(rowKey.get());
                String oKey = inKey.split("#")[0];
                byte[] bSales = columns.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("sales"));
                String sSales = new String(bSales);
                Integer sales = new Integer(sSales);
                context.write(new Text(oKey), new IntWritable(sales));
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class hbaseReducer extends TableReducer<Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            try {
                int sum = 0;
                for (IntWritable sales : values) {
                    Integer intSales = new Integer(sales.toString());
                    sum += intSales;
                }
                Put insHBase = new Put(key.getBytes());
                insHBase.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("sum"), Bytes.toBytes(sum));
                context.write(null, insHBase);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
// define scan and define column families to scan
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf"));
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(HBaseMapReduce.class);
// define input hbase table
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("test1", scan, hbaseMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
// define output table
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("test2", hbaseReducer.class, job);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to compile the code using this command:

```
javac -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH -d hbase_classes hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java
```

I get the following error:

```
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TableMapper
  location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableReducer;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TableReducer
  location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class TableMapReduceUtil
  location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class hbaseMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class TableMapper
  location: class HBaseMapReduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable rowKey, Result columns, Context context)
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class hbaseMapper
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    public static class hbaseReducer extends TableReducer<Text, IntWritable, ImmutableBytesWritable> {
                                             ^
  symbol:   class TableReducer
  location: class HBaseMapReduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: class hbaseReducer
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("test1", scan, hbaseMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
        ^
  symbol:   variable TableMapReduceUtil
  location: class HBaseMapReduce
hbase/HBaseMapReduce.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob("test2", hbaseReducer.class, job);
        ^
  symbol:   variable TableMapReduceUtil
  location: class HBaseMapReduce
9 errors
```

I can successfully compile and run usual MapReduce code. The problem begins with using the MapReduce package inside the HBase package; i.e.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce
```

My environment variables:

```
#Hadoop Related Options
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/ubuntu/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/nativ"
#HBase related options
export HBASE_HOME="/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hbase"
export HBASE_CONF="$HBASE_HOME/conf"
export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
#MapReduce Options
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$($HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop classpath)
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=$($HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase classpath)
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_CLASSPATH
```

Comment: did you try to print `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` env var and see what's the value?

Comment: yeah it is a very long value. cannot copy here

Comment: You should ideally be using maven/gradle instead to compile your code.